# Generate zip file on the fly with javascript

Tags: javascript, zip, client

I would like to know the best solution/way to generate zip file(s) from the html/css stuff on the current page through javascript.

Comment: Did you search some js libraries? https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/

Comment: @DenisFrezzato one of the main issue in all libs is that uses Blob to download that have issues in Safari.